# Javascript- Disable listview column once clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview

I have a asp listview that displays columns. If it's edittable it puts the text in a textarea box and allows a user to edit it. 
What I'm struggling with is once one address is clicked and being editted I want to disable any other address from being able to be editted.

Is their a way to ignore the click functions on the 'originalType' span if a textarea is showing?

```
<asp:ListView ID="table" >
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table >
        <thead>               
            <th>
                Address Type
            </th>
            <span>
            <th>
                State
            </th>
            </span>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="item" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="abc">
        <td width="40%">
            <span class="originalType" id="original">                    
                    <span class="TypeSpan" style="display:none;"><%# DataBinder.Eval("AddressType")%></span>                                     
            </span>                
                    <span data-enabled="false" class="EditType" style="display:none">                   
                    <textarea class="edit"><%# DataBinder.Eval("AddressType")%> </textarea>  
                    <input type="button" class="button3 buttonSave" id="buttonSave" value="Save" />
                    <input type="button" class="button3 buttonCancel" id="buttonCancel" value="Cancel" />                                               
            </span> 
        </td>

        <td width="45%">

        </td>
        </span>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EmptyItemTemplate>
  </EmptyItemTemplate>
 <EmptyDataTemplate>    
 </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: you should avoid nesting anything in a `span` as it is meant to be inline, use `div` instead which is meant to be block

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
newEditBox.attr("data-enabled" == "true")
```

Should be

```
newEditBox.attr("data-enabled", "true")
```

Also when are you setting it to "false" ?

Comment: This isn't quite right its still allowing me to open the textarea of another edittable address type when their already is one opened. I set it back to false if the user clicks cancel button or after the save button method runs through

Comment: try and check if the value of newEditBox.attr("data-enabled") is false or "false"

Answer (score 0):

if youre checking the value the correct way is
    
    `newEditBox.attr("data-enabled") == 'false'`